# child theme performance / avoid import and minify JS files

Tags: child-theme, performance

I am working on a child theme and I have been having troubles with the performance. The parent theme is not very good and I cannot see a way to improve the speed of the child theme at least a little bit.

One of the things is that the parent uses "import" on its original stylesheet. They import Foundation and one webfont. I need to import the parent stylesheet into the child stylesheet. Is there any way for me to change the 'import' within the parent stylesheet without messing it up?

Another thing is that the parent theme uses lots of JavaScript files, most of them are not minified. Would it be appropriate for me to minify the parent files and put them all into a single file?

Comment: import cannot be changed from child theme.

Comment: If your parent theme is a lot of bull, scrap it and get a new theme. There is no use trying to fix a poorly written theme with a child theme. It'like trying to swim in a pool of syrup :-)

Comment: Hi, @PieterGoosen. The parent theme isn't a complete BS, but it does have problems. I cannot start with a new one, unfortunatelly. It has to do with clients and graphic designers, long story. So, I just wonder if there would be any tecnique, or any trick, that would help me to improve the performance by fixing problems on the parent theme. I did all I could on the child theme (compressions, minifyings etc etc), but I still have some problems that come from the parent theme - that is only bad in this specific aspect: performance.